# How to get chat conversations in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, chat

I try to add messages system in my application built with codeigniter 3, and lucky for me the messaging system was working great but am having problem show chat conversations. I try to query my database and I use group so it can group without displaying same users multiple time and it works.

The problem I am having is that as am using group order by are not working so the system can not get convos base on recent chat.

Here is my code:

```
public function getTopHeaderConvos($uid)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('zd_messages');
    $this->db->join('zd_users', 'zd_users.user_id = zd_messages.msg_from_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('zd_messages.msg_to_id', $uid);
    $this->db->order_by('zd_messages.msg_id DESC, zd_messages.msg_read ASC');
    $this->db->group_by('zd_users.user_id');
    $this->db->limit(5);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try to cut the orderby line and paste it below groupby line